# How to make the webpage scroll automatically in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, wkwebview

I'm doing my graduate project.
I'm making an simple view ios app that detects your lookat point using ARFaceAnchor and use this information to scroll the webpage.
BTW, the webpage is displayed by WKWebKit, not SafariServices.
I didn't find the relative functions to solve this problem.
Thanks very much!

Comment: If you know the point user looking at you can try this function : `webView.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect: CGRect, animated: Bool)`

Comment: You can also set your web view's contentOffset directly.

Comment: If you want to scroll to the top with animation for example, it should be `webView.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect: .zero, animated: true)`

Comment: Thank you very much! The function `scrollRectToVisible` is useful, but there is another problem. Since the look-at point is on the screen, the coordinate of that point is changing in a very small scale. Because the coordinate of the point is relative to the screen, not the webpage, so no matter how long the webpage is, it will automatically scroll to a nearly fixed position. How to solve that problem?